# How to match word INCLUDING word with hyphens?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using the following regex to match words with hyphens:

`/\b\w*[-']\w*\b/`

However, it doesn't match words without hyphens. How can I turn it into a regex that also matches words without hyphens?

Comment: `/\b\w*[-']*\w*\b/`?

Comment: You could likely use `\b[\w'-]+\b` and that would do both.

Comment: @l'L'l Hey that's the answer. Could you post it as one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can eliminate the `\w*` on both sides of the character class and just use:

```
/\b[\w'-]+\b/
```

That should match word characters with hyphens or without that are at least >= one character long.

Answer (score 0):

This should match words that include, but don't end in hyphens:

```
/\b\w+([-']\w+)+\b/
```

It should match:

- abso-lutely
- honey-don't
- runner-up-athon

It won't match these non-words:

- its'
- pre-
- -ing